# Importing multiple pgm pictures using read.pnm() in R

Tags: r, image

Is there a way how to import multiple .pgm image files using read.pnm?

I've tried creating a list of files and then using lapply for importing all images.

```
allFiles <- list.files(path = "faces_subset", pattern = ".pgm", full.names = T)
pictures <- lapply(allFiles, FUN = read.pnm())
```

The error message I get is

Error in file.info(file) : argument "file" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the file name to the read function, as in

```
allFiles <- list.files(path = "faces_subset", pattern = ".pgm", full.names = T)
pictures <- lapply(allFiles, FUN = function(f) read.pnm(f))
```